# Java - Learning the difficulties with synchronized

Tags: java

So my teacher posted some code with examples of synchronized code and non synchronized and he is trying to teach us the differences between putting synchronized on a method and a block of code. I dont see the difference in his code by running the application but perhaps you guys can see it and explain. Ill post the code and if there is something missing with the information that im giving you guys just leave a comment and i will edit as soon as  possible. So there are two classes which are related to each other. And these are the following. The commented methods are the one that im supposed to try. So the first method im supposed to run with synchronized  public int incCounter() { and without. The rest of the methods im supposed to run without synchronizing  public int incCounter() {. But i dont see the difference.

```
   package f6; 
public class Counter1Thread extends Thread {
    private Counter1 counter;
    private int times;

    public Counter1Thread(Counter1 counter, String name, int times) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.setName(name);
        this.times = times;
    }

    // Testa med Counter1-incCounter a) utan synchronized b) med synchronized
//    public  synchronized void run() {
//      int value;
//      System.out.println(getName() + " startar");
//      while (times-->0) {
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(1000);
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
//          value = counter.incCounter();
//          System.out.println(getName()+": "+value);
//      }
//    }

      // testa med Counter1-incCounter utan synchronized
//    public synchronized void run() {
//      int value;
//      System.out.println(getName() + " startar");
//      while (times-->0) {
//          try {
//              Thread.sleep(1000);
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
//          synchronized(counter) {
//              value = counter.incCounter();
//          } 
//          System.out.println(getName()+": "+value);
//      }
//    }


//     testa med Counter1-incCounter utan synchronized
//    public void run() {
//      int value;
//        System.out.println(getName() + " startar");
//        while (times-->0) {
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(1000);
//            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
//          synchronized(counter) {
//              value = counter.incCounter();
//              System.out.println(getName()+": "+value);
//          }
//        }
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter1 counter = new Counter1();
        Counter1Thread ct1 = new Counter1Thread(counter,"A",20);
        Counter1Thread ct2 = new Counter1Thread(counter,"B",20);
        ct1.start();
        ct2.start();
    }
}


package f6;

import java.util.Random;

public class Counter1 {
    private int counter;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public int incCounter() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        return counter;
    }

//  public synchronized int incCounter() {
//      counter = counter + 1;
//      return counter;
//  }   
}
```

Comment: There is so much code commented out that I do not see what parts are troubling you. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe add also what would be the result you are expecting by calling those methods and what is the actual behavior. This will help filling out the "knowledge gaps" you're asking about.

Comment: Hey guys, to clarify a little. I dont know what calling those methods should give as an result but what i do get is. A startar:  B: startar:  A:1 B:2  and it keeps going randomely it could be like B: 2 B:3 A:4 B:5. Whats troubling me with trying those methods is that i get the same outcome with the last 2 methods or maybe there is a small difference that im not realizing. I thought by giving the whole code of the two classes would make it easier for you guys to see the difference.

Comment: I have to shake my head at any teacher who demonstrates synchronization using `synchronized` on the `run` method of a `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `synchronized` on the `run` methods don't do anything in these examples.  You should ignore these.  They are at best an example of randomly and incorrectly placed synchronization statements.

The key differences between the implementations are the differences between the (commented out) examples one and three: Example one has no synchronization around the increment operation, while the third example wraps increment with a synchronized statement:

```
value = counter.incCounter();
System.out.println(getName()+": "+value);

synchronized (counter) {
    value = counter.incCounter();
    System.out.println(getName()+": "+value);
}
```

The third example is the equivalent of the fourth example:

```
public synchronized int incCounter() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    return counter;
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
public int incCounter() {
    synchronized (this) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Note that `this` from this fourth example is the same as `counter` from the third example.

What you should see is that the un-synchronized example doesn't reliably increment the counter.  (You may not see the effect every time you run the test, as the result will depend on the timing of the two threads which are used by the test.)

Comment: Thank you! I will have to blame my teacher for misunderstanding the workings of synchronization in java :)